# Reverse the text using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write text reversely, finally I did it using regular expression but I thing I am using too much of lines for doing this.

It is working perfect "eoJ nibreM". **I think can write it to single line.**

My code is

```js
function reversetext(){
 var text =  $("#input_output").val();
 text = text.replace(/\r\n/g,'\n');
 text = text.replace(/\(/g,'  (  ');
 text = text.replace(/\)/g,'  )  ');
 text = text.replace(/\[/g,'  [  ');
 text = text.replace(/\]/g,'  ]  ');
 text = text.replace(/\{/g,'  {  ');
 text = text.replace(/\}/g,'  }  ');
 text = text.replace(/\</g,'  <  ');
 text = text.replace(/\>/g,'  >  ');
 text = text.split('').reverse().join('');
 text = text.replace(/  \(  /g,')');
 text = text.replace(/  \)  /g,'(');
 text = text.replace(/  \[  /g,']');
 text = text.replace(/  \]  /g,'[');
 text = text.replace(/  \{  /g,'}');
 text = text.replace(/  \}  /g,'{');
 text = text.replace(/  \<  /g,'>');
 text = text.replace(/  \>  /g,'<');
 $("#input_output").val(text);
}
$(window).load(function(){
  reversetext();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input_output">Merbin Joe</textarea>
```

can any one reduce this code?

Comment: i think you don't need a regex for this.

Comment: Yes, We can do it through css properties right? But I would like to do using regex, for learning !!!

Comment: Can the delimiters be nested? In other words, do you want to handle input such as `(Merbin <Joe>)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really something RegEx is suited for; it's more about matching patterns that string manipulation.

You can do this very simply with `split`, `reverse`, and `join`

```
var reverseString = function(string){ 
return string.split('').reverse().join('');  
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't handle what he wants to do with the `()[]{}<>` delimiters. In other words, he seems to want to transform `(Merbin Joe)` into `(eoJ nibreM)`, not `)eoJ nibreM(`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method with looping:

```
var name = "Joe Dirt", reverse = "";
for(var i=name.length-1;i>-1;--i){
    reverse+=name[i];   
};
console.log(reverse);
```